# Why W3 validator fails?

Tags: html, validation, android-browser

When I use Chrome, Firefox or Opera i have no problem with my website under Desktop computer, but when I use default Android browser (also on Google search preview), right menu does not show up. I checked on W3 validator website, but for index page, it says it cannot be checked:

http://volkangezer.scienceontheweb.net/index.php

For another page:

http://volkangezer.scienceontheweb.net/iletisim.php?dil=en

It shows some errors, but probably they are not the reason for this problem.

My first question is why my index.php page cannot be checked? The both pages have exactly the same encoding and include files.

Second question is, why right menu does not show up?

Thank you.

Comment: When you get an answer to a question, the appropriate response is not to edit that question away and thus make the answer appear to be irrelevant to what you asked. I've rolled the edit back.

Answer (score 4):

The validator tells you why it can't check it:

> Sorry, I am unable to validate this document because on line 350 it contained one or more bytes that I cannot interpret as utf-8 (in other words, the bytes found are not valid values in the specified Character Encoding). Please check both the content of the file and the character encoding indication.
>
> The error was: utf8 "\xC4" does not map to Unicode

In other words, either your file is screwed up or it is encoded using a character encoding that doesn't match the one it claims to use.

See [Character encodings for beginners](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding.en) and the documents it links to for more information on the subject.

Comment: Thanks i will try it, but what about my second question? do you have any idea?

Comment: No idea, and aside from being about the same document, it isn't related to the first question at all.